# È corretto dire "afferrare un pesce dalla coda" invece di "afferrare un pesce per la coda"?

Tags: prepositions

Nel [vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/afferrare) ci sono alcuni esempi di uso del verbo "afferrare" con la preposizione "per":

> *a. qualcuno per le mani, per le vesti, per il collo*.

Dunque, immagino che "afferrare un pesce *per* la coda" sia un'espressione corretta. Io però ho cercato di scrivere una frase con l'espressione "afferrare un pesce" ed ecco quello che è venuto fuori:

> L'uomo ha afferrato il pesce *dalla* coda.

Non sono sicura però che la preposizione "dalla" sia corretta in questa frase. È così?

Se entrambi i costrutti sono corretti, c'è qualche differenza di significato, di uso o di frequenza di uso tra i due?

Answer (score 1):

Dal punto di vista della grammatica sono corrette entrambe.

Tuttavia c'è una leggera differenza: di solito, prendere "dalla" coda sta a significare che l'animale è nelle vicinanze e lo catturi senza spostarti, mentre prendere "per la" coda dà più l'immagine di un inseguimento.

Di solito non si rincorre... un pesce! Quindi forse è preferibile la prima, *suona meglio*.

Se invece si fosse trattato, ad esempio, di un topo o una lucertola sarebbe stata più sensata la seconda.

Comment: Sono d'accordo sul fatto che siano corrette tutte e due, ma sinceramente non sono d'accordo sulla differenza semantica che gli attribuisci, mi sembra più un'interpretazione personale. Oltretutto (e qui forse c'è la mia di interpretazione personale) a istinto direi addirittura il contrario, ovvero che tra le due la seconda sia la forma più corretta e propria . Comunque magari mi sbaglio io.

Comment: sì, certamente è una mia interpretazione personale. non ho fonti a supporto.

Comment: Anche a me "dalla coda" suona strano.

Comment: Il *toro* però viene proverbialmente preso **per** le corna